# Pandas plotting in Windows terminal

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ipython, interactive

I have a simple pandas data frame. Trying to plot from the Windows 10 terminal session of IPython gives me this:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 'X':[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]})

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   X  Y
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9

In [6]: df.plot(kind='line')
Out[6]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x26c4d366940>

In [7]:
```

I can not see any plot. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need `plt.show()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can try add `%matplotlib inline` or `ipython notebook --matplotlib inline` for a notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
#ipython notebook --matplotlib inline 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 'X':[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]}) 

df.plot(kind='line')
```

Or you can add `plt.show()` for a console:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 'X':[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]}) 

df.plot(kind='line')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Start your IPython session with the option `--matplotlib`:

```
ipython --matplotlib
```

This should give you a second window after this line `df.plot(kind='line')` and pressing `<Enter>`.:

[image]

You can keep the window open. For example:

```
In [4]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
In [5]: plt.title('Test')
Out[5]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x1124ed908>
```

Now you should see the title *Test* on your plot.
If it does not update try `draw()`:

```
In [6]: plt.draw()
```

Comment: Starting IPython with 'ipython --matplotlib' did start IPython but without any other window.

Comment: The window should come up when you create your plot: *after this line `df.plot(kind='line')` and pressing <Enter>.*

Comment: Ok, thanks. Based on your answer and the answer before it seems to me that using 'ipython --matplotlib' makes the flag '--matplotlib' redundant.